# Unable to find file (getResource)

Tags: java, sqlite, file, resources

I have a following project structure:

[image][image]

I want to open file **user_config.db** in **SQLiteConnector** class and i use the following code:

```
public boolean isDatabaseFileExist(){
  File databaseFile = new File(getClass().getResource("/remotecontrolserverfx/databases/user_config.db").toString());
  return databaseFile.exists();
}
```

And it always returns `false`. How to fix?

*Thanks in advance. Regards...*

Comment: It is `remotecontrolserverfx.databases` not `remotecontrolserverfx/databases`

Comment: Are you sure? It's just such a project structure in the IDE.

Comment: The folder's name is `remotecontrolserverfx.databases`. Try it.

Comment: Look in the description again, this is not a folder name...

Comment: Then why did you post an image that does not show the actual path?

Comment: @Dev0ps check my below answer, worked for me. you have to remove leading `/` character from the file path and check whether getResource() method returning null or not.

Comment: And you have to use `getClassLoader()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this; Note that leading "/" is removed from file path.

```java
public boolean isDatabaseFileExist(){
  return this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("remotecontrolserverfx/databases/user_config.db")!=null;
}
```

If you want to get the `File` object;

```java
File databaseFile = new File(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("remotecontrolserverfx/databases/user_config.db").getFile());
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you show me how to get the real path to this file?

Comment: `this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("remotecontrolserverfx/databases/user_config.db").getFile()`

Comment: And I can, if need be, create a file along this path?